# Flask committing to Heroku, flask-lesscss never loading

Tags: git, heroku, flask, less

Running flask and able to commit most my app but consistently getting stuck on the following line after doing `git push heroku master`.

Nothing happens, there is no error, it just does not load.

Here is the last 2 lines. Seems like it is unable to reach the `flask-lesscss` site but I am not sure how to fix.

```
remote:        Obtaining flask-lesscss-v0.9.1 from git+http://github.com/sjl/flask-lesscss.git@724e999f6d728be81f057ac4d5ebc8d9757b950e#egg=flask_lesscss-v0.9.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 21))
remote:          Cloning http://github.com/sjl/flask-lesscss.git (to 724e999f6d728be81f057ac4d5ebc8d9757b950e) to ./.heroku/src/flask-lesscss-v0.9.1
```

Any advice?